# WGET downloaded website not working properly

Tags: ubuntu, wget

I downloaded a website using WGET. After download and links converted, I can't get certain resources.

For example,
a CSS file saved with `index.min.css?update=2` doesn't load.
But if I open the link in a new tab and change the link to `index.min.css%3fupdate=2`, the file loads.

Many files are saved in such a pattern. How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Downloading a website is very rarely perfect. In many cases, manual fixing is
still required afterward.

Some advice for common problems:

- The wget call should use the parameters `--adjust-extension` and `--convert-links`.
  The option `--adjust-extension` makes wget save the PHP files with a `.html` extension,
  while `--convert-links` makes wget convert the links in the downloaded files to the
  newly created `.html` files (but only after all files have been downloaded).
- When file-names contain special characters, you may use
  `--restrict-file-names=nocontrol` or `--restrict-file-names=ascii`.
- When wget gets wrong the character encoding, you may specify
  `--remote-encoding`, as perhaps `--remote-encoding=utf-8`.

(This list is by no means exhaustive and may not apply to your problem.)

Comment: Can I fix it with .htacess. Is there a way to URL encode all incoming request for assets such as CSS,images